# Boost::signals2 and const-ness

Tags: c++, signals2

having some observable class, the way I naively use signals2 is to provide a member signal so that anybody can connect

```cpp
struct Observable {
  boost::signals2::signal<void(Observable const *)> aSignal;
  void foo() {
    //something happens
    aSignal(this);
  }
};
```

For a better encapsulation, maybe adding some public `subscribe` and hide `aSignal` to avoid external classes to invoke the signal.

Now, the thing is that `boost::signals2::signal::connect` method is `non-const` which is understandable since the list of connections is modified. However, this prevents using signals for just-observing classes, which just want to react to the modification of the `Observable` without modifying it.

```cpp
struct Observer {
  //here I need to pass a non-const Observable
  Observer(Observable * observed) : connection(observed.aSignal.connect(std::bind(this,&Observer::react) {}
  void react(Observable const *) {
    //do something to const Observable
  }
  boost::signals2::scoped_connection connection;
};
```

A way to get around the problem is to make `mutable` those signals that send `const this` and `const subscribe` functions.

```cpp
struct Observable {
  void foo() {
    //something happens
    aSignal(this);
  }
  template<typename aFoo>
  boost::signals2::connection subscribe(aFoo && foo) const {
    return aSignal.connect(std::forward<aFoo>(foo));
  }
  private:
  mutable boost::signals2::signal<void(Observable const *)> aSignal;
};
```

Is that an anti-pattern?

Another way around is maybe using an intermediate proxy class that allows connecting to const and to non-const Observable, but then I would lose any advantage of having signals already coocked for me.

Or I just have to give up const-correctness?

Or there is something that I am missing?